# primefaces barchart extender how to set tick interval dynamically

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

I am using primefaces bar chart with an extender. I want to get Dynamic tick intervals.

Can I pass the bean variable as value for tick interval in extender?

How can I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I set the max value of extender from bean and this is my code

```
<h:outputScript >

      function ext() {  

         this.cfg.axes.xaxis= {

                     min: 0, 
                     max:"#{myBean.maxValue}",
                     numberTicks: 11,
                     pad: 2,
            }; 
}

</h:outputScript>
```